Excel count number of eldest in each school
I have a list of children that are divided into two schools. I'd like to count the number of eldest in each of the two schools. Below is an example.
I managed to count the number of families (unique name occurrence) with the formula =SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A2:A9,A2:A9)) which I found on the web. It is unclear to me how this formula works but it seems to provide the correct answer.
Now I'd like to count how many families have their eldest child in school A (3: the Smiths, the Taylors, and the Williamses) and how many families have their eldest child in school B (2: the Joneses and the Browns).

EDIT: I'd like the formula only count one eldest in case of twins (Robert and Linda Taylor in the example).
I managed to do it by adding intermediate formulae in columns F, G, and H:

Formula in F2: =MINIFS($C$2:$C$9,$A$2:$A$9,$A$2:$A$9)
Formula in G2: =A2&F2
Formula in H2: =(COUNTIF($G$2:$G2,$G2)=1)+0

Finally, to compute the number families that have their eldest child in school A (in B12): =SUMPRODUCT((H2:H9)*(D2:D9="A")).
Is there a way to directly write a single formula?


=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C9=MINIFS(C2:C9,A2:A9,A2:A9))*(D2:D9="A"))

So, you want a COUNTIFS on the School, and the Year, where Year is a MINIFS based on School?

Solution proposed by @Michal works great!

Based on @Michal and @Mayukh Bhattacharya
answers, the formulae to use for the example are:

Number of families that have their eldest child in school A:


=ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A9&"|"&C2:C9,(MINIFS(C2:C9,A2:A9,A2:A9)=C2:C9)*(D2:D9="A"))))


Number of families that have their eldest child in school B:


=ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A9&"|"&C2:C9,(MINIFS(C2:C9,A2:A9,A2:A9)=C2:C9)*(D2:D9="B"))))



Using MINIFS() function to get the minimum child birth year for each family name:



MINIFS(C2:C9,A2:A9,A2:A9)



Comparing with Child Birth Year range to get the TRUE and FALSE where TRUE means the one which has matched



=MINIFS(C2:C9,A2:A9,A2:A9)=C2:C9



Matching those with one of the Schools here it is A, which returns TRUE and FALSE and when there is array multiplication, the matching TRUE from above gives 1 while the other 0



(D2:D9=A12)


Returns 1 and 0's
=(MINIFS(C2:C9,A2:A9,A2:A9)=C2:C9)*(D2:D9=A12)



Now, wrapping within FILTER() to extract the children that are eldest as well as based on the school; merged into one Col A and C



=FILTER(A2:A9&"|"&C2:C9,(MINIFS(C2:C9,A2:A9,A2:A9)=C2:C9)*(D2:D9=A12))



Since, we need unique counts, therefore wrapping within UNIQUE() to get the same. Refer the last screenshot, it shows it returns duplicates based on the TRUEs



=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A9&"|"&C2:C9,(MINIFS(C2:C9,A2:A9,A2:A9)=C2:C9)*(D2:D9=A12)))



Finally, wrapping within ROWS() to get the counts of the array. One can use COUNTA() as well, but personally, I prefer in using SUM()


=ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A9&"|"&C2:C9,(MINIFS(C2:C9,A2:A9,A2:A9)=C2:C9)*(D2:D9=A12))))


Alternative, with SUM()
=SUM(N(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A9&"|"&C2:C9,(MINIFS(C2:C9,A2:A9,A2:A9)=C2:C9)*(D2:D9=A12)))<>""))


And as it seems you have access to UNIQUE() & FILTER() should have access to LET() as well, then why not define variables to avoid using repeated ranges/functions and enhance the performance by reducing the redundancies (if any)


=LET(
     a, A2:A9,
     b, C2:C9,
     c, MINIFS(b,a,a),
     SUM(N(UNIQUE(FILTER(a&"|"&b,(c=b)*(D2:D9=A12)))<>"")))


Suggestions: If you ever face issues in understanding the formulas, the better way is to write down each formulas used one by one or select the formulated cell, goto Formulas Tab --> Under Formula Auditing Group --> Select Evaluate Formula --> Click Evaluate to understand. The screenshot shows below:



You don't even need SUMPRODUCT, I still keep thinking in terms of "old-school Excel", SUM will work as well.

@Michal I have a pb with the formula when there are twins. The formula counts 2 eldests.

You could try this: =ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A9&"|"&C2:C9,(MINIFS(C2:C9,A2:A9,A2:A9)=C2:C9)*(D2:D9=A12))))

@MayukhBhattacharya this formula returns the error "#CALC!".

@TVG what is your version of Excel?

@TVG see works on my end btw do you have any empty? Refer Screenshot

@MayukhBhattacharya Oh I see now, you're making reference to A12. I've changed A12 by "A" or "B" and it works fine now. Would you like providing the details of your formula in an answer to this post? I think it would be very valuable. Thanks!

I have not done anything special. I have applied the same as you did. If you follow minutely. And the credit goes to you and @Michal. There is nothing big difference see. Using FILTER() I am extracting the ones which are eldest as well as based on the school, next wrapping it within UNIQUE() to get unique valuses lastly wrapping within ROWS() to get the counts. I am not adding it. Because you should have the credit

@MayukhBhattacharya I've tried to provide an explanation. Please fill free to edit the post. It is not perfectly clear to me how this works. Especially "&"|"&".

@TVG are you able to understand now?

@MayukhBhattacharya That's a fantastic edit! Very informative! You should have written your own answer because you really deserve all the credit.

@TVG not a problem

Let me explain you how the formula works.
To start with: you don't need SUMPRODUCT(), SUM() is enough.
Next, the situation of SUM(1/COUNTIF(...): imagine you have three entries: 'a', 'b' and 'c'. Each of them has a different amount of occurences, as you can see:



entry
number of occurences
reciprocal of occurences




a
3
1/3


a
3
1/3


a
3
1/3


b
1
1/1


c
4
1/4


c
4
1/4


c
4
1/4


c
4
1/4



When calculating the sum of those reciprocals, you get 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 (three times) + 1/1 (one time) + 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/4 (four times), leading to 1 + 1 + 1, meaning the amount of entries.
Like this, you can understand that the formula =SUM(1/COUNTIF() is in fact a way to get COUNT_DISTINCT() (but that latter function does not exist :-) ).

Thank you very much! That's very clear!

It is a nice explanation but I would always add the rider that if I had the Unique function, I would use that, and if not, Frequency https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273

When there are multiple eldest ones, select the first one:
TAKE(FILTER(first, (family = fn) * (birth_year = eldests_year)),1))

=LET(data, A2:D9, family, INDEX(data, , 1), first, INDEX(data, , 2), birth_year, INDEX(data, , 3), school, INDEX(data, , 4),
    u_family, UNIQUE(family),
    eldests_year, MINIFS(birth_year, family, family),
    eldest_one, MAP(
        u_family,
        LAMBDA(fn, TAKE(FILTER(first, (family = fn) * (birth_year = eldests_year)), 1))
    ),
    in_school, LAMBDA(fn,eldest,sch,
        SUM((family = fn) * (first = eldest) * (school = sch))
    ),
    num_eldest_in_school, LAMBDA(sch,
        HSTACK(
            "# eldest in school " & sch,
            SUM(MAP(u_family, eldest_one, EXPAND(sch, ROWS(u_family), , sch), in_school))
        )
    ),
    VSTACK(
        HSTACK("# families", ROWS(u_family)),
        num_eldest_in_school("A"),
        num_eldest_in_school("B")
    )
)


